# fingerprint scanner not detected?

Tags: drivers, 20.04, kernel, fingerprint-reader

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my HP Envy x360. LSUSB detects the fingerprint scanner, but FPRINTD does not detect the hardware. Since LSUSB detected it, is there a chance I could get it to work?

```
phenom@PhenomFire:~$ lsusb

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04f3:0c4c Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:ARM-M4
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0408:542a Quanta Computer, Inc. HP Wide Vision HD Camera
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The second device (`04f3:0c4c Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:ARM-M4`) is the fingerprint scanner.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the output of `lsusb`? Not every Envy x360 uses the same reader. Please note that *detection* does not always mean *usable*. The operating system may know that something exists but, without a driver that's able to interact with the hardware, it may not be able to use it.

Comment: ELAN:ARM-M4 being my fingerprint scanner

Comment: It appears that this device currently [does not have Linux support](https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=usb:04f3-0c4c).  See also [here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/-/issues/281) and [here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/wiki/-/wikis/Unsupported-Devices).

Comment: use this link
https://fprint.freedesktop.org/supported-devices.html to verify if your device is supported by fprintd, if it is then try this
sudo systemctl status fprintd.service and paste here the output.

Answer (score 0):

The fingerprint sensor is currently unsupported in `fprint`. [Here is a list of supported devices.](https://fprint.freedesktop.org/supported-devices.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt install -y fprintd libpam-fprintd
sudo pam-auth-update
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I compiled and installed from the source. Make sure you have `git` installed.

```bash
sudo apt install libcairo2-dev meson ninja-build libgusb-dev  libgirepository1.0-dev libnss3-dev libgudev-1.0-dev gtk-doc-tools valgrind
sudo ldconfig
git clone https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/geodic/libfprint.git
cd libfprint/
git switch elanmoc2
git pull
meson build
cd build
ninja
sudo ninja install
```

Source answer by [uvigii](https://askubuntu.com/a/1454483/280579)

Also after the build you could test the examples from `build/examples`

eg. this enrolls new fingerprint

```bash
examples/enroll
```

eg. to check if provided fingerprint is correct

```bash
examples/verify
```

Comment: what after `sudo ninja install` do I need to do on an Ubuntu to use the fingerprint reader to login?