# Cannot enable fingerprint scanner in Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: gnome, compatibility, fingerprint-reader, lsusb, 21.10

I recently switched my HP ENVY cg0xxx laptop (which has a built in fingerprint scanner) from windows 10 to Ubuntu 21.20 (GNOME 40.4.0) (not dual boot, windows is gone). Everything has worked well so far, except I cannot use the fingerprint scanner. Under the guide provided by Ubuntu I should have the option under **Settings > Users > Enable fingerprint scanning**. However, there is no option for this when I navigate to the users section.

Someone recommended to run `lsusb`

which returns:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f3:0c4c Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:ARM-M4
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f2:b6b6 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HP Wide Vision HD Camera
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I Would be lying if I said I knew what this meant, would anybody be able to advise me how to troubleshoot this problem? Many online threads for HP devices have been uninformative.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1342122/fingerprint-scanner-not-detected Same device, read the comments, follow the links. No change since then, still unsupported.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem with slightly different sensor from the same company. It looks like the sensors are weird and require modified libfprint library, gonna try it tomorrow.

Here's the thread for my sensor:
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/-/issues/263

Fork for Elan sensors:
https://github.com/iafilatov/libfprint

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1194612)