USB fingerprint reader in Ubuntu 22.04
I bought a fingerprint scanner, but I can't install it on Ubuntu 22.04. The system recognizes it as a USBKey Module. The seller sent a link to the software, but it didn't help. https://drive.google.com/file/d/13PkCYil_nP-yeqF3OJmDlJQP2COYY3Oi/view?usp=share_link




Did the seller tell you it works with Ubuntu 22.04? Seems it would be their job to get it working. It seems this came from some kind of China knock off shop. I suggest you try for a refund.

did you follow this https://askubuntu.com/questions/191390/how-to-use-sudo-command-to-install-tar-gz?

Seller AliExpress.  They refer to the description "Linux Support" and don't know anything else.  I'm trying to contact the manufacturer, but so far I haven't been able to.

I repacked tar.gz into deb, but Ubuntu does not see the scanner.

Then I suggest you follow David's advice talk to AliExpress

Yes, I contacted AliExpress, hope it helps.   Thank you!

How to make Ubuntu understand the ID Device 2109:7638 as a fingerprint scanner?

This might give you an idea though it is not for your scanner https://askubuntu.com/questions/1342122/fingerprint-scanner-not-detected
